# How to filter array based on Text and Date range picker in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, search, filter, datepicker

I have an `input` where users can search for titles.
Date picker which is used [mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker). (Any other picker is welcome)

How can the array be filtered by only Search, only Date, or both Search and Date? (Search via Title works ).

How would the search be in array vs nested array?

HTML-

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search" /></div>  
<date-picker v-model="datefilter" range></date-picker>

<div v-for="item in resultQuery">
 {{item.title}}
</div>
```

Vuejs-

```html
<script>
  import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker';
  import 'vue2-datepicker/index.css';

  export default {
    el: '#app',
    components: { DatePicker },
    data() {
      return {
        search: null,
        resources:[
            {title:"AAA",date: 1622192760},
            {title:"BBB",date: 1622624760},
            {title:"CCC",date: 1620810360},
            {title:"DDD",date: 1625907960},
            {title:"EEE",date: 1623315960},
        ],
        resources2:[
            {id:1,items: [{ title: 'a',date: 1622192760 }, {name: 'aa', date: 1622624760 }]},
            {id:2,items: [{ title: 'b',date: 1623315960 }, {name: 'bb', date: 1625907960 }]},
            {id:3,items: [{ title: 'c',date: 1622624760 }, {name: 'cc', date: 1622624760 }]},
            {id:4,items: [{ title: 'd',date: 1622624760 }, {name: 'dd', date: 1622624760 }]},
            {id:5,items: [{ title: 'e',date: 1622192760 }, {name: 'ee', date: 1622624760 }]},
        ],

        datefilter: null,
      };
    },
    computed: {
    resultQuery(){
      if(this.search){
      return this.resources.filter((item)=>{
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())) }
      })
      }else{
        return this.resources;
      }
    }
  }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could factor out the filtering into its own functions:

```js
const byDate = (item) => {
  const itemDate = new Date(item.date);
  return itemDate >= new Date(this.datefilter[0]) &&
         itemDate <= new Date(this.datefilter[1])
}

const byTitle = (item) =>
  item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
```

Then pass them into `this.resources.filter()` when the search field isn't empty or when a date range is selected:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    resultQuery() {
      //...
      let results = this.resources

      if (this.search) {
        results = results.filter(byTitle)
      }

      const hasDateFilter = this.datefilter?.length >= 2 && this.datefilter[0] && this.datefilter[1]
      if (hasDateFilter) {
        results = results.filter(byDate)
      }

      return results
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/filtering-results-in-vue-ehn9o?file=/src/App.vue)